# Setting Venkman context (it's stuck on "JavaScript Debugger")

Tags: javascript, firefox

After a positive experience with Venkman for XUL development some time ago, I am trying it on a page in Firefox now.  I am a bit rusty and can't get over the first hurdle of setting the cono page to the console's evaluation context.

My procedure:

1. Installed Venkman add-on from mozilla.org
2. Loaded my page and selected Tools -> JavaScript Debugger
3. When Venkman comes up, select Open Windows tab and expand "Browser Window"
4. Right-click my page and select "Set as Evaluation Object". The console title changes, indicating **contect: example_page.html**.
5. In the console, I input *document.title* but the result is still "JavaScript Debugger"

Does anybody have any thoughts? For this job, I really would prefer Venkman.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless somebody has a better solution, I'm going with...

### Use Firebug instead.